# NetworkD3 Sankey Plot in R: How to switch text labels from the right to the left of the inner nodes only

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I created a Sankey Plot using the NetworkD3 R package. Below is an example of the output:

[Sankey Plot Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CyRT.jpg)

I used the following code for the Sankey:

```
sankeyNetwork(Links = SankeyLinks, Nodes = SankeyNodes, Source = "source",
          Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "names", 
          fontSize = 14, nodeWidth = 20,nodePadding = 15,NodeGroup = "nodeColor",
          colourScale = JS(ColourScale), LinkGroup = "linkColor",
          sinksRight = T)
```

The network generates text labels to the right of the middle nodes, which crowds the links to the leaf nodes. I would like to switch the text to the *left side* of the inner nodes *without* changing the text placement on the beginning node  and leaf nodes (right and left, respectively).

I have researched a similar question: [Place text values to right of sankey diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215306/place-text-values-to-right-of-sankey-diagram)

Here is another:
[How to place node title to the left or right of the node in d3 Sankey graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960985/how-to-place-node-title-to-the-left-or-right-of-the-node-in-d3-sankey-graph)

The answers are coded in D3.js, which I have not yet learned and don't know how to implement into my R code, or they are moving text labels to the right of the nodes.

Any suggestions that I can implement into R to move text of the inner nodes to the left would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Using the example code given in the comment, when I use the set.seed it doesn't create inner nodes, so maybe that is the issue?
[Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRuKa.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from @timelyportfolio's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36213873/4389763), you can modify it to filter to any subset of nodes before applying the formatting...

```
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

links <- data.frame(
  src = c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6),
  target = c(3,6,4,5,5,6,7,9,8,9,7,10,7),
  value = 1
)

nodes <- data.frame(name = c(1, 2, 3,
                             "Middle 1", "Middle 2", "Middle 3", "Middle 4", 
                             4,5,6,7))

sn <- sankeyNetwork(
  Links=links, Nodes=nodes, Source='src', Target='target',
  Value='value', NodeID='name', fontSize=16,
  width=600, height=300,
  margin = list("left"=100)
)

sn

sn <- onRender(
  sn,
  '
  function(el,x){
  // select all our node text
  d3.select(el)
  .selectAll(".node text")
  .filter(function(d) { return d.name.startsWith("Middle"); })
  .attr("x", x.options.nodeWidth - 16)
  .attr("text-anchor", "end");
  }
  '
)

sn$jsHooks$render[[1]]
# $code
# [1] "\n  function(el,x){\n  // select all our node text\n  d3.select(el)\n  .selectAll(\".node text\")\n  .filter(function(d) { return d.name.startsWith(\"Middle\"); })\n  .attr(\"x\", x.options.nodeWidth - 16)\n  .attr(\"text-anchor\", \"end\");\n  }\n  "
# 
# $data
# NULL

sn
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @CJYetman for your input, and showing that filtering by nodes that start with specific words would be necessary. but when running onRender function (both on my own data and when using your example code) the text isn't changing to the left side of any nodes, let alone the filtered ones.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. What version of `networkD3` are you using?

Comment: Based on timelyportfolio's comment in his/her onRender function, it seems his goal was to make all node text match, not move text from the right to left side. I am unfamiliar with Java at this point. Is there a way to adjust the onRender function to move the text of the inner nodes from right to left?

Thanks again.

Comment: The `filter` command determines which nodes are affected. The following two `attr` commands set the attributes of the text that determine where it displays.

Comment: Can you post an image of the output you get? Maybe your viewer window is too small?

Comment: Hmm, so it should be working. When I run the onRender function it seems to refresh the plot in the Rstudio viewer window, but the image isn't changing.

Comment: I edited my original post to add an image of the output I am seeing when using your example code. I'm looking to flip the side of the text for the intermediate level nodes, not the leaf nodes, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I added an image of the output from the example code in my answer.

Comment: I made an example that uses fixed data and has "middle nodes", so that it's more specific to what you were asking. (It would have been easier in the beginning if you provided the data you are working with).

Comment: It still doesn't work when I run that code in R studio (refreshes the plot and the result hasn't changed). I tried expanding the viewer window to the max, but no luck. It's obviously something weird on my end, because it works in your post. I have both networkD3 and htmlwidgets packages installed and loaded, so I'm not sure what it could be.

Thanks again for the help, and I'll make sure to provide data next time as well.

Comment: The plot should not be refreshing. There’s no command there that should print the plot except that last command `onRender()`.

Comment: Right. I was checking the plot after running the sankeyNetwork command and then when I ran the onRender command it refreshed and still has the text on the right. Which is weird because it seems to work for you using the same code.

Comment: trying saving the output of the `onRender()` function also, just like with the `sankeyNetwork()` function (e.g. `sn <- onRender(`...), then inspect the `sn` object to see if the JS code is getting added properly.... like `sn$jsHooks$render[[1]]`

Comment: I modify the code again, so that it plots the unmodified sankeyNetwork, then uses the `onRender()` function to modify the `sn` object and saves the modified object over top of itself, then inspects the `sn` object to make sure the JS was properly added to it, then plots the `sn` object again with the modification. Make sure that the `htmlwidgets` package is loading properly, and that the `onRender()` function is working without error.

Comment: I removed the html widgets package and re-installed. When running the library command R says the "JS object is masked from package htmlwidgets."

So I ran the onRender function as "htmlwidgets::onRender, and it didn't make a difference.

Also, when I re-installed htmlwidgets i get the following message: "  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
                    binary, source,   needs_compilation
htmlwidgets,    0.8,    0.9,             FALSE".

Comment: There also is a message: Warning in tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers) :
  Check shiny:::toJSON and make sure htmlwidgets:::toJSON is in sync. When I check it says: Error: 'toJSON' is not an exported object from 'namespace:shiny'

Comment: you should restart R, load `htmlwidgets`, then slowly and carefully loading one-by-one each other package you're trying to use and thoroughly reading the output in the console after each loading... that will tell you which package is masking `JS` from `htmlwidgets`

Comment: I restarted R, loaded htmlwidgets, and then found networkD3 is masking JS from htmlwidgets. I tried uninstalling htmlwidgets and networkD3, but it didn't make a difference. If I load networkD3 first, then htmlwidgets masks JS from networkD3.

Comment: Maybe you should post a new question to get your R setup working properly? StackOverflow tends to discourage super long comment threads like this.

Comment: When I reinstall htmlwidgets, R recommends restarting R because it needs to update packages that are currently loaded. When I proceed with restarting R it says, "Error in `parent.env<-`(`*tmp*`, value = data$enclos) : 
  reached elapsed time limit," but continues to successfully install htmlwidgets. In the console it recommends to check shiny::toJSON, which seems to work after loading htmlwidgets WITHOUT networkD3 loaded, but when I load networkD3 an error is returned. Does any of this help identify the problem?

Comment: I can do that. Thank you for helping so much.

Answer (score 2):

I'll edit only CJ Yetman answer, his answer is awesome and very helpful.

The error was in this line of code in his function

```
  .filter(function(d) { return d.name.startsWith("Middle"); })
```

Here's what i did to make it works

```
onRender(
        sn,
        paste0('
        function(el,x){
        d3.select(el)
        .selectAll(".node text")
        .filter(function(d) { return (["',paste0(Middle,collapse = '","'),'"].indexOf(d.name) > -1);})
        .attr("x", 6 + x.options.nodeWidth)
        .attr("text-anchor", "end");
        }
        ')
)
```

I didn't use `startsWith()`function and used `indexOf()`, and middle is a variable in R which is,

```
Middle <- c("Middle 1","Middle 2","Middle 3","Middle 4")
```

Comment: String.prototype.startsWith() does not work on IE, but otherwise it has been widely available for a while. But you are correct, you can filter the nodes that you want to affect in various ways. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith